# Can't connect to MS SQL Server with new user

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I am currently setting up an MS SQL Server and created a new Database user. Gave that user all admin roles for that server and Login is enabled. But still I am not able to login with that user. The error message says that the connection was established but there is no answer from the other side of the pipe which makes no sense at all as I can login with every other user and am not using remote connection.

**This is the error message:**

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to IIS-SCHNI015.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)

For help, click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-233-database-engine-error

---

No process is on the other end of the pipe

### END OF ERROR MESSAGE

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Post the *actual* error you get, rather than describing it. Have you checked the SQL Server logs too, to see if you see any connection errors there?

Comment: you should check in ssms the user if he is activated and which roles he has

Comment: Make sue `Remote Login` is enabled ala  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16#to-configure-the-remote-access-option

Comment: Remote Login is enabled